# Connecting to SQL Server - "Login Failed" via Visual Studio Server Explorer, works in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a new SQL Server instance on 13.0.5598 that I can connect to and manipulate with no issues via SSMS. I was able to create a new table and manipulate it. However, through the Visual Studio Server Explorer (Professional 2017), I can connect to the database and the test ping succeeds, but trying to create anything or even open a query window results in the following error:

[image]

I've tried the advanced connection properties with no luck. My current connection string is as follows (XXXX's replacing sensitive info):

```
Data Source=SQL-D-16T3084.XXX.XXXXX.COM;Initial Catalog=SEApps;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=u1054f898567b48aa9da254d80b1c1109;
TrustServerCertificate=True;Packet Size=4096;Context Connection=False
```

**Added for clarity: What is different about the database interaction between Visual Studio Server Explorer and SSMS? I assumed they would interact with the database in the same way.**

Comment: Check the logs on the server and then if you don't understand the error from there, post the error in your question as an [edit].

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the Management folder of the server, unless there's another way to see the log.

Comment: Then I would suggest speaking to your DBAs for assistance.

Comment: Shouldn't VS Server Explorer and SSMS interact in a similar way with the database? That is what I found surprising here... Also, this is a database instance hosted on Cloud Foundry, I don't think there is a DBA, or at least not in the traditional sense.

Comment: If one connects, and the other days want, the the connection details aren't the same; but as we don't have any of those details we can't tell you what. This is why I suggest talking to your DBA who can tell you the error, and you can troubleshoot with them.

Comment: In answer to your question: yes they should connect in the same way.